# Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ BCM2837B0 Pythonで制御するには？

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+には、BCM2837B0が搭載されています。
どうやら公式ページを調べると、データシートはBCM2835のものを参照すればよいようです。
　https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf

Pythonでアドレスに直接書き込みペリフェラルを制御したいのですが
Pythonでそのような制御は可能なのでしょうか？
やはり低レベルなC言語で書く必要がありますか？

Comment: こんなのが見つかりますよ。[Raspberry Pi 3でpythonを使ってLチカ](https://hombre-nuevo.com/microcomputer/raspberrypi/raspberrypi0010/)

Comment: @kunif やりたいのは、C言語だと「volatile unsigned int addr = 0xAAAABBBBU; (unsigned int *)addr |= 0xFF;」のような実装です。このようにアドレスに直書き込みする制御がPythonで実装できるか？という質問です。調べてもぱっと見では出てこない。Pythonに詳しくないので質問してみた次第です。

Comment: こんな記事で [Raspberry Pi and /dev/mem access](https://www.element14.com/community/thread/32147/l/raspberry-pi-and-devmem-access?displayFullThread=true)  `RPi.GPIO` モジュールで /dev/mem アクセスが出来るようなので、Python でも出来るのではないでしょうか。